# Is Yearling update working?

Tags: support, badges

I've been due a "Yearling" badge on Chemistry https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/5354/feetwet for days and not received it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're at exactly 200 reputation, meaning you've *earned* 199 (since you always start with 1).

At least, that's how I read the badge description.

From [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/262755)

> Have a reputation of at least (number of years as an active user) × 200 + 1 (starting reputation)

Comment: Ah ha.  Let's see if two points fixes that...

Comment: Yep -- 202 did it.  Guess I should break off the other question....